# Office365 group's member cannot send email as group's email account

Tags: office-365, outlook-365

How can a user send email as the assigned group's shared email account?

**More detail:**

Our company has an office365.com account.

User `someone@company.com` is a member of a group with **`info@company.com`** shared mailbox.

But `someone@company.com` cannot send email as **`info@company.com`**. In fact, there is only the main email address `someone@company.com` in the **From** combo-box of the user.

Answer (score 2):

If you spend a minute searching, you will find all the articles are how Send As permissions *should* work with Office 365, Exchange Online and Outlook 2016. We read them all and were still getting (despite checking and re-checking permissions):

> This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send
>   the message on behalf of the specified user.

With the error code:

> 0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524

The solution was to:

1. Go into the Exchange admin center (EAC) > recipients > shared
2. in the shared mailbox, check "Hide from address lists"
3. Save
4. Wait for change to propagate
5. Go back in and clear the "Hide from address lists" checkbox
6. From Outlook, add the address as a "From" addres.
7. Account Settings > Account Settings > Email > the Exchange account > More Settings > Advanced > Add -- add the shared mailbox name.
8. In Accounting Settings > Download Address Book > download the Global Address List

May need to restart Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

This [Office 365 Help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-as-a-distribution-group-address-20073) from GoDaddy should address your problem.

### Send as a distribution group address

If you are an Office 365 admin, you can give members of a distribution group the permission to send as the distribution group address.

1. In your Office 365 account, click on **Dashboard**.
2. Click **Launch Office 365**.
3. Log in using your Office 365 email address, and password.
4. Go to the Exchange Admin Center.

> Only the primary admin account will be able to log in to the Exchange
>   Admin Center.

5. Under **recipients**, click on **groups**.
6. Select the distribution group you want to edit.
7. Click **Edit**.
8. Click **group delegation**
9. Decide whether you want to assign **Send As**, or **Send on Behalf** permissions.

> **Send As**
>   This allows a member of the group to send email as the distribution group address. To a recipient, the From line will display the group, only.
>   **Send on Behalf**
>   This allows a member of the group to send email on behalf of the group. To a recipient, the From line will display the sender "on behalf of" the group.

10. Click **Add**, and find the members to whom you want to assign **Send As** and/or **Send on Behalf** permissions.
11. Click **Save**.

In order to send as the distribution group, you need to show the **From field** in your email composer. To show the From field in Outlook, open a new email, click **Options**, and select **From**.